# A macro to move a row from one wksheet to another in the same workbook after status change

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a workbook with 2 worksheets (1 sheet called final, 1 sheet called pending)  that use the same column headings and column formulas.

I am having a hard time figuring out a macro/VBA that will help me automatically transfer rows of data from the "pending" sheet to the "final" sheet once the status of the fourth column changes from pending to final. This is so that all the data for pending and final clients are kept on  separate sheets.

Please help.

Comment: What software are you working with? "HTML" is probably not the right tag.

Comment: Sorry. I am working with excel. Its the first time I've ever asked a question. =)

Comment: Thank you so very much for the edit =D I appreciate it much!

Comment: One of the easiest ways of studying VBA code and getting an outline of what you need to do is to actually record the macro. You can then use the generated code as a 'template' of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on your woorkbook code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Sh.Name = "pending" And Target.Column = 4 Then
    If Sh.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column) = "final" Then
        Sh.Select
        Sh.Rows(LTrim(Str(Target.Row)) & ":" & LTrim(Str(Target.Row))).Select
        Selection.Copy ' or cut
        Sheets("final").Select
        Rows("20:20").Select ' here is your destination row... you must set a global to control it...
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End if
End Sub
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Paulo. I'm new to this Q&A session. I do not know why I can only see a strip of what you wrote. =(